# Doctrine's orphanRemoval strange behaviour?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Scenario

```
class Foo
{
    [...]
    /**
     *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bar", mappedBy="foo", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
     protected $bars;
}

class Bars
{
    [...]
    /**
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Foo", inversedBy="bars")
     */
     protected $foo;

    [...]

    public function setFoo(Foo $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
        $foo->addBars($this); //PAY ATTENTION TO THAT LINE

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Ok, let's assume I have a FormType to persist `Foo` and add or remove `Bars`

```
class FooType
{
    [...]

    $builder
        ->add('bars', 'collection', array(
            [...]
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype_data' => new Bar(),
}
```

If I don't specify `orphanRemoval=true` option I need to do some manual extra work to remove `Bar`s entity from `Foo` when I get the form posted without `Bar`s that were there. I will not include code as it works and is not a problem.

As soon as I use `orphanRemoval=true` (commenting out the "extra work code, that basically check for db bars before bind the form and delete bars that are no longer posted), something strange happens: regardless if I try to add or remove `Bar`s from `FooType`, the result is that every relation between `Foo` and `Bar`(s) is destroyed.

If I comment out `$foo->addBars($this);` into `Bar`'s `setFoo(Foo $foo)` method, all works.

Questions

1. Why this happens?
2. How can I resolve without removing `$foo->addBars($this)` (if possible?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was about `by_reference` attribute: without this attribute, things gets messy and doctrine seems not to be able to handle this situation.

Solution

```
class FooType
{
    [...]

    $builder
        ->add('bars', 'collection', array(
            [...]
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype_data' => new Bar(),
            'by_reference' => false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Doctrine Docs

> When using the orphanRemoval=true option Doctrine makes the assumption that the entities are privately owned and will NOT be reused by other entities. If you neglect this assumption your entities will get deleted by Doctrine even if you assigned the orphaned entity to another one

Once you remove `page` from `book` all references have been deleted and there is no relation between the two

you could try and call `addBars($this);` from the controller and see how it works out